# IE8 too slow to start with Spybot immunising same system

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, anti-spyware, spybot-sd

IE8 (upgraded from IE7) on XP, is far too slow to start when the system is already is immunised with [Spybot - Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/spybotsd/index.html) - it seems that this is the problem.

I've been using SS&D for some years now without problems, so if it's possible I'd be more confident to keep using it than IE's new security feature.

What is the right way (without breaking things) to get IE8 snappier on a setup like this, is SS&Ds immunisation now redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until there is a solution I've reverted back to IE7, which works fine with SS&D.

Answer (score 2):

You can look in IE8's add-on manager to find out what exact add-on or plug-in is causing a slowdown. There is a load time column in that list. At least those contribute to slow tab creation as well.

As for SS&D: Well, personal computer security usually is "feeling secure" and not "being secure". But IE does some very good things to limit damage something can do. And you don't necessarily click on any link that promises [dancing bunnies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_bunnies), right?

Comment: Definitely worth investigating. The last time I visited, my sister's IE 8 was taking more than 2 minutes to load(!!)  I went into the add-on manager and saw a bunch of toolbars and other gizmos apparently installed when installing other apps (though none were malware - there was just a lot of them.)  When I left, load time had gone down to about 10-15 seconds, and I've yet to get a call from her saying "Hey, where's that thing I used to have in IE..."

Answer (score 1):

I suggested trusting IE 8 just test it, run a couple of sites with SS&D disabled and test the speed